# How to Use JPA setMaxResults() (LIMIT 20) Without Entity Manager?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I currently have the following JPA set-up:

```
com.example.entities.Employee
com.example.repository.EmployeeRepository
com.example.controllers.EmployeeController
```

The application settings are pointing to an SQL server and the the controller has endpoints (i.e. '/getEmployees') with no issues.

However, I would like to LIMIT the number of employees that are returning.

After using JPA, **I am not using any entityManager code** as many tutorials suggest.

Instead, I am using the following design pattern in the repository:

**com.example.repository.EmployeeRepository**

```
package com.example.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.entities.Employee;

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT "
        + "e.eid, "
        + "e.firstname, "
        + "e.lastname, "
        + "e.dept) "
        + "FROM Employee e")
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees();

}
```

Below is a copy of the controller file for the endpoint:

**com.example.controllers.EmployeeController**

```
package com.example.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.example.entities.Employee;
import com.example.repository.EmployeeRepository;

@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository empRepo;

    @RequestMapping(name = "/getAllEmployees")
    public @ResponseBody List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        return empRepo.getAllEmployees();
    }

}
```

As you can see, there is no mention of **entityManager** in these files and so it is become more of an abstract situation, where I am not sure where I would initiate the setMaxResults(20) method without explicitly using **entityManager**.

I've noticed that **setMaxResults** function is usually attached to a query object:

```
q.setMaxResults(n)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you just modify the query to add something like `LIMIT 20`?

Comment: You're not using EntityManager, so you're not using the JPA API, instead you're using the Spring Data JPA API. Tags fixed

Comment: @csm_dev when JPQL doesn't have "LIMIT" as a keyword that would make no sense

Comment: @Neil Stockton That's why my comment is "_something like_ LIMIT"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using Pageable interface in Spring data?

```
package com.example.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable

import com.example.entities.Employee;

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT "
        + "e.eid, "
        + "e.firstname, "
        + "e.lastname, "
        + "e.dept) "
        + "FROM Employee e")
    public Page<Employee> getAllEmployees(Pageable pageable);

}
```

In your controller you can set how many items you'd like to get :

```
@RequestMapping(name = "/getAllEmployees")
public @ResponseBody List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
    return empRepo.getAllEmployees(new PageRequest(0, 20)).getContent();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

HQL doesn't support LIMIT feature, so you have 2 options here:

- use native SQL query
- use entityManager and setMaxResults